# Makedepend: Command not found

Tags: kernel, lts, make

I'm trying to compile a source code and I'm getting this error

```
make[1]: makedepend: Command not found
```

Do you have any suggestions?

I have Ubuntu 12 04 LTS, 2.6.28-17 kernel and gcc version 4.6.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache search makedepend
xutils-dev - X Window System utility programs for development
```

So you have to install `xutils-dev` package(*which includes the program makedepend*) .Install `xutils-dev` package by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ makedepend
The program 'makedepend' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev
You will have to enable the component called 'main'
```

For future, typing the command automatically searches it inside repository and suggests variants of packages which can be installed in case the command not found in system.

Comment: Worked for me, getting different errors now :D Thank you